# Why I get different result after run this JavaScript code in browser and WebStorm

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webstorm

Code is as followed:

```js
let s1 = Symbol("foo"),
    s2 = Symbol('bar'),
    s3 = Symbol('baz'),
    s4 = Symbol('qux');
let o = { [s1]: 'foo val' };
console.log(o);
Object.defineProperty(o, s2, {value: "bar val"});
console.log(o);
Object.defineProperties(o, {
    [s3]: { value: 'baz val' },
    [s4]: { value: "qux val" }
})
console.log(o);
```

I get the result in **WebStorm**

```
{ [Symbol(foo)]: 'foo val' }
{ [Symbol(foo)]: 'foo val' }
{ [Symbol(foo)]: 'foo val' }
```

and I get the result in **Chrome**

```
Symbol(foo): "foo val"}
{Symbol(foo): "foo val", Symbol(bar): "bar val"}
{Symbol(foo): "foo val", Symbol(bar): "bar val", Symbol(baz): "baz val", Symbol(qux): "qux val"}
```

Comment: you will see the same result as in WebStorm if you run `node <your file>.js` in terminal.

Comment: Must be caused by stringifying Symbols (this is what the `console.log()` does implicitly). The resultant object is properly expanded in dev tools console and in WebStorm debugger console (when debugging either HTML or Node.js scripts)